# .NET Core 3.1 Identity takes too long to login on Azure

Tags: c#, sql-server, azure, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

We've built a .NET Core 3.1 MVC web app.  We decided to go with MS Identity Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity and Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UI.  We scaffolded out all the login / user management stuff.  It created Razor Pages in \Areas\Identity\Pages\Account.

We needed to have a Username not tied to email address.  We also needed to extend IdentityUser and add things like FirstName, etc.

This Line of code in \Areas\Identity\Pages\Account\Login.cshtml.cs is giving us hell.  On local machines, with local DB's it runs just fine.  When we push to Azure, it takes 30 seconds to execute this line.

```
var result = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(Input.UserName, Input.Password, Input.RememberMe, lockoutOnFailure: false);
```

In fact anything that uses _signInManager takes 15 - 30 seconds.  Even something as simple as logging out.

```
private readonly SignInManager<ApplicationUser> _signInManager;
```

ApplicationUser inherits from IdentityUser

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public string UserType { get; set; }

    public int OrganizationID { get; set; }

    public DateTime? CreatedOn { get; set; }

    public string NPINumber { get; set; }
}
```

We assumed this might be because we were using a low-end hosting tier on Azure, so we kicked everything up a few notches, threw more money at it, and are still having problems.

This is really causing an issue.  I'm open to any ideas to correct this.

Comment: I saw your reddit post, did you see this: https://forums.asp.net/t/2083413.aspx?Entity+Framework+take+about+30+second+to+do+login+ Note the deploy in Release mode and the last comment to try ADO.Net instead of the ASP Identity to confirm that is the bottleneck.

Comment: Thank you for your comment.  I tried the release mode and changing some configurations around for deployment - none of that seemed to help.

Turns out it was a misconfiguration in Nlog.  Who woulda guessed that?  All the evidence pointed to _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync.

Turns out it was the logging that happened around _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync.

Answer (score 2):

Turns out someone gave me an idea that helped me find the clue that was causing the slowdown.

Application Insights.  I turned it on on Azure... Logged in, logged out... Dug deep into the bowels of what was happening, and saw a reference to (localdb)\mssqllocaldb which absolutely should not be on the production server.

This led me to believe that NLog was misconfigured. Turns out, NLog was setup to log to a .log file but ALSO add a record to a table in the DB.

On local dev machines, it would log correctly to the local DB. But on Azure, it would also TRY to log to Server=(localdb)\mssqllocaldb; which of course it couldn't reach. It took 30 seconds or so to time out.

Removing those references having NLog post to (localdb)\mssqllocaldb; fixed the slowdown.  Logins and logouts are pretty zippy now.

It was NOT Microsoft's Identity solution as it seemed. It was instead logging and misconfigured NLog that was causing the issue.

I guess I need to take a closer look at Application Insights. I was under the impression it was just some spammy MS shit to data mine my users behavior. I guess I was very wrong.

Lesson here is that it *seemed* like it was Microsoft's Identity solution, but was in fact screwed up logging that happened every time Identity was used.